# How to prevent human inferiority syndrome?

Tags: interspecies-relations, races

We love to create people with "cool" abilities and traits. So much so that it is very common in sci fi and fantasy to have peoples (aliens, elves, etc.) with extra-human powers, and yet still have normal humans living alongside them.

This begs the question: in a universe with, for example, one super-strong, super-fast species and another that can literally move stuff with their minds, what makes human beings worthy of sharing equal partnership in the galactic space empire or the multi-kingdom alliance? Perhaps the aliens/elves/whoever are convinced they are "the superior species". Are they right? Human Joe can't ever match Alien Bob in a fistfight, or compete with Elven Kara's ability to change a lightbulb at the apex of a fifty-foot ceiling without ever moving from her position on the floor.

I've noticed a common attempt to level the playing field comes in this form: "Well, the aliens/fantasy beings may have cool powers, but human PSYCHOLOGY is unique!" Humans are clever and stubborn little bastards who never give up when they are supposed to and can invent stuff way faster than any other species because they are so darn imaginative! Or maybe humans have a unique propensity for violence that is shocking to all the other species, allowing human beings to invent new way to fight/kill things that would never occur to anyone else! The civilized and sophisticated Elven Kara people would never dream of warring against and killing another being so horribly unless their own survival was drastically threatened! The number of wars, episodes of genocide, etc. committed by humanity over their history is simply unthinkable to anyone else!

But this answer of unique human psychology runs into a problem when your aliens/fantasy creatures are also protagonists in the main crew, or even viewpoint characters, who need to have flaws and psychology that are relatively familiar to the reader. What if your "clever inventor starship engineer" is alien Bob? Or your badass never-say-die heroine is Elven Kara?

Perhaps you don't want to pigeonhole all characters of a certain species by installing tropes like "Elven Karas are all super good at math" and "Alien Bobs have zero immaginiation"? Sure, perhaps there are some small differences, like "alien Bobs *tend* to have slightly better spacial awareness", but even so maybe these shouldn't be more pronounced than those subtle ones that exist, for example, between the sexes, and as in that case, would likewise be a *trend*, not a rule, allowing for the inevitable exceptions.

So, if you don't resort to a gimmick about human cleverness or will-power or capacity for violence being unique to the species, since your other-species characters are also capable of being imaginative, stubborn, and violent, what makes humanity worth their position in the world? Much like in superhero stories, where the superheros begin to multiply and the human characters begin to wonder what good they are in comparison, or feel threatened by how helpless they are comparatively, are human beings in such a world doomed to feel inferior (and be told they are by other species?) Sure, if humanity there has modern ideals and believes that being an intelligent being is enough to give you value, that's great, but can we count on the other species feeling the same way? Heaven knows we've had enough real cultures with very opposite opinions among the human species alone.

Comment: Please edit the question to offer a specific problem to be answered. As it stands now it risks being closed as unclear. (We already have here on Earth quite a few species who are *"for example, super-strong [and] super-fast"*, and yet we do not feel inferior to horses or cheetahs or rhinoceroses. And if the world in question includes a species which *"can literally move stuff with their minds"* then it includes magic, and magic does not need any rational explanation.)

Comment: There's the saying that goes "God made man, Sam Colt made men equal". In a technologically advanced society, especially one that's at an interstellar stage, individual physical differences mean nothing and value nothing. This person can run 30 mph, well so what, there's almost no mundane situation in which having such speed would be really beneficial, especially when you have cars that can go 200 mph.

Another option would be maybe _not_ making your aliens into Hat Species, whose shtick is x? Why do they have to have "powers", anyway?

Comment: @AlexP We don't feel inferior to horses, cheetahs, and rhinos because we have a means of feeling superior to them: intelligence. If they were as sentient and smart as we are, with opposable thumbs that allow them to do the same things we do, things might be different. And regardless of whether or not magic exists, if it only works for one species you still have the issue at hand.

Comment: @DarthBiomech giving a species a special power, like telekinesis, does not in and of itself a hat species make. Giving all characters of the same species the same general traits and skills and mindset, (which is some of what I am objecting to in the initial question!) that is what makes a Hat Species. Still, upvote on your comment for the mention of technology. I think that can indeed big a big playing field leveler, and maybe the start of an answer?

Comment: From the [help], section "what question should I avoid asking?": your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for answering a question with a question: How did Humans go from plains walking apes to the apex species on the planet? Answer: Sweat and throwing.

Forget all that stuff about making tools and spears, or farming and domestication. Anyone can do that. Humans have *sweat* and *monkey shoulders*.

Humans used to practice *persistence hunting* and part of what made that possible was the ability to *sweat* (and a foot mechanism that makes it easy to jog for a long time). Most other animals pant to regulate their temperature, which is really inefficient when compared to sweating across the majority of your surface area. Additionally, humans *throw things*. Sure, other apes do that too, but there aren't many that *hunt* using it.

So what do Humans do that other species can't? Endurance jobs and jobs that require the accurate judgment of distance by the eye. It doesn't matter that Alien Bob is ten times stronger than Human Joe, Human Joe can work for eight hours with fewer breaks than Alien Bob so he gets more work done. And Elven Kara can *tell* you what angle to throw something to hit it, but she needs extra tools to measure distances and do the throwing for her cause her shoulders and binocular vision don't compare to Human Joe's.